# Does the repeal of net neutrality remove monopoly protections from ISPs?

Tags: united-states, internet

The repeal of net neutrality was done (in part) by declassifying ISPs as title II [common carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_carrier). As I understand it, being a title II common carrier implies being treated like a utility under a government regulatory body.

I've been told that this offers monopoly protections for ISPs, since they aren't operating with complete autonomy. In many areas, people have one choice for ISPs. As a utility, that's almost expected (I didn't have a choice with my water provider either), but as a typical company, that's arguably a monopoly. I've also been told that if net neutrality is dismantled, and ISPs are declassified as common carriers, that this removes these protections.

Is this true? Does the repeal of net neutrality remove monopoly protections from ISPs?

Comment: I don't know about de jure protections, but unless the DOJ does something arguably unthinkable, they're de facto gonna be staying as is.

Comment: It's not clear that there *are* any de jure protections arising from classification as a "common carrier", so determining that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Trucking companies are common carriers, but are surely not monopolies either in law or in fact. Dense urban areas often offer a choice of 2 or more ISP service, once this is profitable. It does not appear that ISPs were offered the kind of legal protections that some utilities have been.

Comment: Can you first explain "net neutrality" and after that, "the repeal" of whatever it was?